# events not related to current month

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm having an issue here and wanted to know if anyone have any idea of how to accomplish this. The best example is here http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ if you look at the calendar, notice the last event "4p Repeating Event" lands on "Friday, July 2nd" but shows in June. Is there a way to get rid of this for June?

Is there anyone that can help???

Answer (score 0):

not possible yet. here is the feature request:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=166

please star it to receive updates